# Expand Tabs to Spaces in C?

Tags: c, tabs

I need to expand tabs in an input line, so that they are spaces (with a width of 8 columns).  I tried it with a previous code I had replacing the last space in every line greater than 10 characters with a '\n' to make a new line.  Is there an way in C to make tabs 8 spaces in order to expand them?  I mean I am sure it is simple, I just can't seem to get it.

Here's my code:

```
int v = 0;
int w = 0;
int tab;
extern char line[];

while (v < length) {

   if(line[v] == '\t')
      tab = v;

   if (w == MAXCHARS) {
      // THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK
      line[tab] = ' ';
      // set y to 0, so loop starts over
      w = 0;
   }
   ++v;
   ++w;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a question about the C language; it's a question about finding the right algorithm -- you could use that algorithm in *any* language.

Anyhow, you can't do this at all without reallocating `line[]` to point at a larger buffer (unless it's a large fixed length, in which case you need to be worried about overflows); as you're expanding the tabs, you need more memory to store the new, larger lines, so character replacement such as you're trying to do simply won't work.

My suggestion: Rather than trying to operate in place (or trying to operate in memory, even) I would suggest writing this as a filter -- reading from stdin and writing to stdout one character at a time; that way you don't need to worry about memory allocation or deallocation or the changing length of line[].

If the context this code is being used in *requires* it to operate in memory, consider implementing an API similar to `realloc()`, wherein you return a new pointer; if you don't need to change the length of the string being handled you can simply keep the original region of memory, but if you *do* need to resize it, the option is available.

Answer (score 4):

You need a separate buffer to write the output to, since it will in general be longer than the input:

```
void detab(char* in, char* out, size_t max_len) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (*in && i < max_len - 1) {
        if (*in == '\t') {
            in++;
            out[i++] = ' ';
            while (i % 8 && i < max_len - 1) {
                out[i++] = ' ';
            }
        } else {
            out[i++] = *in++;
        }
    }

    out[i] = 0;
}
```

You must preallocate enough space for `out` (which in the worst case could be `8 * strlen(in) + 1`), and `out` cannot be the same as `in`.

**EDIT:** As suggested by Jonathan Leffler, the `max_len` parameter now makes sure we avoid buffer overflows.  The resulting string will always be null-terminated, even if it is cut short to avoid such an overflow.  (I also renamed the function, and changed `int` to `size_t` for added correctness :).)

Comment: It might be a good idea to encourage people to write code that avoids buffer overflows - so pass a size for `out` into the function and make sure you don't get a buffer overflow.

Comment: And also isn't the function removing tabs - so the name would be better as 'detab()' than 'entab()'?

Comment: `expand_tabs` would by my choice.  =]

Comment: I would have gone with `copy_detabifyingly()`, but I was concerned that might conflict with something in the standard library. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do something like this:

1. Iterate through the string once, only counting the tabs (and the string length if you don't already know that).
2. Allocate `original_size + 7 * number_of_tabs` bytes of memory (where original_size counts the null byte).
3. Iterate through the string another time, copying every non-tab byte to the new memory and inserting 8 spaces for every tab.

If you want to do the replacement in-place instead of creating a new string, you'll have to make sure that the passed-in pointer points to a location with enough memory to store the new string (which will be longer than the original because 8 spaces or 7 bytes more than one tab).

Comment: Inserting 8 spaces for every tab doesn't align text in columns the way tab is expected to work.  Step #3 needs to insert spaces until the position in the output line is a multiple of the tab width.

Comment: "Is there an way in C to make tabs 8 spaces in order to expand them?" Kinda sounds like the OP wants a plain substitution "1 tab -> 8 spaces". Not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reentrant, recursive version which automatically allocates a buffer of correct size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct state
{
    char *dest;
    const char *src;
    size_t tab_size;
    size_t size;
    _Bool expand;
};

static void recexp(struct state *state, size_t di, size_t si)
{
    size_t start = si;
    size_t pos = si;

    for(; state->src[pos]; ++pos)
    {
        if(state->src[pos] == '\n') start = pos + 1;
        else if(state->src[pos] == '\t')
        {
            size_t str_len = pos - si;
            size_t tab_len = state->tab_size - (pos - start) % state->tab_size;

            recexp(state, di + str_len + tab_len, pos + 1);
            if(state->dest)
            {
                memcpy(state->dest + di, state->src + si, str_len);
                memset(state->dest + di + str_len, ' ', tab_len);
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    state->size = di + pos - si + 1;
    if(state->expand && !state->dest) state->dest = malloc(state->size);
    if(state->dest)
    {
        memcpy(state->dest + di, state->src + si, pos - si);
        state->dest[state->size - 1] = 0;
    }
}

size_t expand_tabs(char **dest, const char *src, size_t tab_size)
{
    struct state state = { dest ? *dest : NULL, src, tab_size, 0, dest };
    recexp(&state, 0, 0);
    if(dest) *dest = state.dest;
    return state.size;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *expansion = NULL; // must be `NULL` for automatic allocation
    size_t size = expand_tabs(&expansion,
        "spam\teggs\tfoo\tbar\nfoobar\tquux", 4);
    printf("expanded size: %lu\n", (unsigned long)size);
    puts(expansion);
}
```

If `expand_tabs()` is called with `dest == NULL`, the function will return the size of the expanded string, but no expansion is actually done; if `dest != NULL` but `*dest == NULL`, a buffer of correct size will be allocated and must be deallocated by the programmer; if `dest != NULL` and `*dest != NULL`, the expanded string will be put into `*dest`, so make sure the supplied buffer is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
int v = 0;
int tab;
extern char line[];

while (v < length){
  if (line[v] == '\t') {
    tab = (v % TAB_WIDTH) || TAB_WIDTH;
    /* I'm assuming MAXCHARS is the size of your array. You either need
     * to bail, or resize the array if the expanding the tab would make
     * the string too long. */
    assert((length + tab) < MAXCHARS);
    if (tab != 1) {
      memmove(line + v + tab - 1, line + v, length - v + 1);
    }
    memset(line + v, ' ', tab);
    length += tab - 1;
    v += tab;
  } else {
    ++v;
  }
}
```

Note that this is O(n*m) where n is the line size and m is the number of tabs. That probably isn't an issue in practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad ways to convert tabs in a string into 1-8 spaces.  There are inefficient ways to do the expansion in-situ, but the easiest way to handle it is to have a function that takes the input string and a separate output buffer that is big enough for an expanded string.  If the input is 6 tabs plus an X and a newline (8 characters + terminating null), the output would be 48 blanks, X, and a newline (50 characters + terminating null) - so you might need a much bigger output buffer than input buffer.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int detab(const char *str, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char *end = buffer + buflen;
    char *dst = buffer;
    const char *src = str;
    char c;

    assert(buflen > 0);
    while ((c = *src++) != '\0' && dst < end)
    {
         if (c != '\t')
             *dst++ = c;
         else
         {
             do
             {
                 *dst++ = ' ';
             } while (dst < end && (dst - buffer) % 8 != 0);
         }
    }
    if (dst < end)
    {
        *dst = '\0';
        return(dst - buffer);
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

#ifdef TEST
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef TEST_INPUT_BUFFERSIZE
#define TEST_INPUT_BUFFERSIZE 4096
#endif /* TEST_INPUT_BUFFERSIZE */
#ifndef TEST_OUTPUT_BUFFERSIZE
#define TEST_OUTPUT_BUFFERSIZE (8 * TEST_INPUT_BUFFERSIZE)
#endif /* TEST_OUTPUT_BUFFERSIZE */

int main(void)
{
     char ibuff[TEST_INPUT_BUFFERSIZE];
     char obuff[TEST_OUTPUT_BUFFERSIZE];

     while (fgets(ibuff, sizeof(ibuff), stdin) != 0)
     {
          if (detab(ibuff, obuff, sizeof(obuff)) >= 0)
              fputs(obuff, stdout);
          else
              fprintf(stderr, "Failed to detab input line: <<%.*s>>\n",
                      (int)(strlen(ibuff) - 1), ibuff);
     }
     return(0);
 }
 #endif /* TEST */
```

The biggest trouble with this test is that it is hard to demonstrate that it handles overflows in the output buffer properly.  That's why there are the two '#define' sequences for the buffer sizes - with very large defaults for real work and independently configurable buffer sizes for stress testing.  If the source file is `dt.c`, use a compilation like this:

```
 make CFLAGS="-DTEST -DTEST_INPUT_BUFFERSIZE=32 -DTEST_OUTPUT_BUFFERSIZE=32" dt
```

If the 'detab()' function is to be used outside this file, you'd create a header to contain its declaration, and you'd include that header in this code, and the function would not be static, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that will `malloc(3)` a bigger buffer of exactly the right size and return the expanded string. It does no division or modulus ops. It even comes with a test driver. Safe with -Wall -Wno-parentheses if using gcc.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *expand_tabs(const char *s) {
  int i, j, extra_space;
  char *r, *result = NULL;

  for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for(j = extra_space = 0; s[j]; ++j) {
      if (s[j] == '\t') {
        int es0 = 8 - (j + extra_space & 7);
        if (result != NULL) {
          strncpy(r, "        ", es0);
          r += es0;
        }
        extra_space += es0 - 1;
      } else if (result != NULL)
        *r++ = s[j];
    }
    if (result == NULL)
      if ((r = result = malloc(j + extra_space + 1)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
  }
  *r = 0;
  return result;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  char space[1000];
  while (fgets(space, sizeof space, stdin) != NULL) {
    char *s = expand_tabs(space);
    fputs(s, stdout);
    free(s);
  }
  return 0;
}
```